# Chrome and Opera rounding up decimal points in height values on Retina Screens

Tags: html, css

I was sure this would have been asked before, but I had a look and can't find anything – I might be using the wrong search terms..

I made a menu button icon for my mobile menu and I used three divs to make the lines, so I could animate them. Now I'm trying to make the lines slightly thinner with a height value of 1.5px rather than 2px, and whilst this works in Safari and Firefox, it doesn't in Chrome or Opera. In these browsers, the height gets rounded back up to 2px.. very annoying. Is there a way around this?

**UPDATE** This seems to be caused by retina displays only, whilst standard displays won't render decimal point pixel values at all.

```css
.menu-button {
  position: relative;
      top: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 21px;
  height: 14px;
  padding: 2px 0 2px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.bar {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 21px;
  height: 1.5px; 
  background-color:#888;

  -webkit-transition: all .8s;
  transition: all .8s;
}

.bar:nth-child(3n) {
  top: 2px;
}

.bar:nth-child(3n+1) {
  top: 8px;
  opacity:1;
}

.bar:nth-child(3n+2) {
  top: 14px;
}
```

```html
 

<span class="menu-button">
  
  <span class="bar"></span>
  <span class="bar"></span>
  <span class="bar"></span>
  
</span>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8nj5y4t1/66/)

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect to happen on the screen if you specify a pixel and a half. Firefox rounds down to 1 pixel.

Comment: "Now I'm trying to *make the lines slightly thinner* with a height value of 1.5px rather than 2px" – this works in Safari and Firefox, but not in Chrome or Opera. 1px is too thin, 2px is too heavy.

Comment: Then make the color slightly transparent. `rgba(136,136,136, .5)`.

Comment: You may have misread my comment. There are no lines 1.5 pixel thick. In the snippet, Firefox makes the line 1px thick and Chrome 2px. (I don't have Safari or Opera here, but I'm pretty sure they can't make 1.5px lines either.)

Comment: Hi, I didn't misread it. My computer is showing those lines in the snippet at 1.5px when viewed in Safari or Firefox. If I remove the ".5", it gets slightly thinner, and if I make it 2px, it gets slightly thicker. I'm not sure why this would be different on your computer, it certainly works this way on mine, I'm on a retina MacBook with all my browsers updated to the latest versions.

Comment: I just checked and I can do 0.5 as well. Maybe this is a retina screen feature?

Comment: Yes, of course! Sorry I didn't think about that; I have only a basic 23" 1920x1080 monitor. You should add that to the question, to avoid confusion.

Comment: That said, my first comment is still valid - on a non-retina screen, Firefox and Chrome display 1.5px differently (one rounds down, the other up) so using this causes cross-browser issues. There is no way around that, so you should consider using whole pixels and semi-transparent colors instead. If desired, you can put the retina-related stuff in an @media query.

Comment: Thanks, will do :)